# how do I call a method from jar file on button click

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, jar, buttonclick

I am a beginner in jsp, java script.
I want to call a method in jar file(.jar : java archive) on a button click. 
Please guide me how to achieve this.

My button is a simple button in jsp file :

```
<input type="button" name="Yes" id="btn_1" value="Yes">
```

And I want to call a jar file method as follows:

```
PBAPI.PictureBook p = new PBAPI.PictureBook(username, password);
p.getname();
```

where, PBAPI is package provided from .jar file. p is instance of it.
And p.getname() will call a method in .java file inside jar.

This function I can invoke as follows:

```
<%
PBAPI.PictureBook p = new PBAPI.PictureBook(username, password);
p.getname();
%>
```

but, this is not done on a button click as it is a plain jsp code.
I want to invoke p.getname(); method only if my button is clicked.
onclick even is handled by javascript as follws:

```
<input type="button" name="Yes" id="btn_1" value="Yes"onclick="callfun()">

<script>
function callfun(){
// But here I am not able to invoke a method from jar
}
</script>
```

Please help..
Thanks.

Comment: no `javascript` runs in client (browser) while `java` (`.jar`) runs in server. Unless you run the `java` in browser as a `java` plugin, in which case `javascript` and `java` plugin can communicate via external interfaces (which is not the case in your question as you mean `JSP` etc..)

Comment: this is one major difficulty in web applications, since they are split in two parts client/browser and server/backend which require complex asyncronous communication to each-other. It is not like usual desktop applications where all the code runs in the same place, time and platform and can communicate at will and ad-hoc